# Fourier transform of a function with finite support.

Tags: fourier-transform, analytic-functions

It is given that a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \to (0,s]$ has the following expansion around infinity
$$ f(x) = \frac{b}{x^{1/3}} \left( a_0+ \frac{a_1}{x} + \ldots \right)$$

Is it possible that this function is the Fourier transform of a function with compact support?

Comment: Are there any more concrete conditions on coefficients $a_0, a_1\ldots,$ and b, we can e.g. set all of them to be 0 :-)

Comment: They are all non-zero. I think I have some idea of the answer. This function $f(x)$ itself can not be the Fourier transform of a function with compact support when you complexify it with $x \to z$. However, if you add appropriate term which has singularity at infinity, you can achieve this. An example of this would be confluent hypergeometric function which is entire function, but its expansion around infinity involves fractional powers.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the Fourier transform of a function is still a function, some integrability condition will be needed. If Fourier transforms of compactly supported $L^2$ functions are actually meant, then they are restrictions of entire functions (of bounded speed of growth) on the real line. Besides, f does not look integrable or square integrable unless $a_0=0$

Comment: The domain of concern is only positive real axis. The function could be divergent when extended to negative real axis. So, we do not have constraint of square integrability. The theorem of interest I am using is Paley-Wiener theorem.  But the question is that can an entire function have expansion around positive real infinity which involves fractional powers. It seems that the answer to this question is 'yes'. The example is confluent hypergeometric function with fractional parameters, which is entire function with asymptotic expansion around $+\infty$ involving fractional powers.